# unable to create a service for SpringBoot on Linux Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, ubuntu-14.04, executable-jar

i just deployed a springboot app 1.4.1.RELEASE on Ubuntu 14.04.5(linode server) but having hard time making it run as service(start, stop, restart). I chanced on http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-service but it didn't help. I can't upgrade the Ubuntu server at the moment to a 16.04.1 since other apps are dependent on this version. I desperately need help on this.

- I tried running

  ~$ sudo ln -s /opt/xxxx/xxxx-0.0.1.jar /etc/init.d/xxxx-0.0.1
- sudo service myapp start

but got response: xxxx-0.0.1: unrecognized service

Please Help

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a strange issue.

For now, I can suggest you do the following things:

- Check if your `*.jar` file is executable. Type `sudo chmod +x /opt/xxxx/xxxx-0.0.1.jar` to be sure about that and start service again.
- Try to copy `*.jar` file to `/etc/init.d/` directory instead of creating link. Type `cp /opt/xxxx/xxxx-0.0.1.jar /etc/init.d/` and start service again.

Let me know if it helped. If not, maybe we can figure out a different solution.

Regards

Comment: Thanks , after following your advise. i am now getting : **/etc/init.d/xxxx-0.0.1: 2: /etc/init.d/xxxx-0.0.1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string**. Please note that my jar is executable and i am able to run it using **java -jar xxxx-0.0.1.jar**

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved with great joy:)

i had to change my pom.xml file from

```
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

to

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

and it worked perfectly...